# Django ORM aggregation with conditional SUM with group by failing

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, orm, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get the follwing query to execute in Django ORM but no luck so far.

I would like to have all PotatoesMeasurement grouped by `wn` and do a conditional count on `alternaria` when it greater than, smaller than and in range of certain values. I have the raw mongosh query to get the correct result but I'm unable to get the equivelent in django ORM.

My model looks like:

```
class BasicEntity(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, blank=True)

class PotatoesMeasurement(BasicEntity):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "measurements_potatoes"

    colorado_potato_beetle_larvae = models.FloatField( default=0.0,
                               validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    aphids_per_leaflet = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    late_blight = models.FloatField( default=0.0,
                               validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    alternaria = models.FloatField( default=0.0,
                               validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    wn = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.now().isocalendar().week,
                             validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(53)])
```

Mongosh query working perfectly:

```
db.measurements_potatoes.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$wn",
      countSmaller: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $lte: ["$alternaria", 1] }, 1, 0] } },
      countRange: { $sum:   { $cond: [{ $range: [ 20, "$alternaria", 30 ] }, 1, 0] } },
      countBigger: { $sum:  { $cond: [{ $gt: ["$alternaria", 90] }, 1, 0] } }
    }
  },
  {$sort: {_id: 1}},
]);
```

On django ORM side so far I have the following:

```
res = (
    PotatoesMeasurement.objects.all()
    .values("wn")
    .aggregate(
        countSmaller=Sum(
            Case(When(alternaria__lt=1, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())
        ),
        countRange=Sum(
            Case(
                When(alternaria__range=[30, 50], then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            )
        ),
        countBigger=Sum(
            Case(When(alternaria__gt=1, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())
        ),
    )
    .order_by("wn")
)
```

The above command fail with the following error:

```
 raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN "measurements_potatoes"."alternaria" < %(0)s THEN %(1)s ELSE %(2)s END) AS "countSmaller", SUM(CASE WHEN "measurements_potatoes"."alternaria" BETWEEN %(3)s AND %(4)s THEN %(5)s ELSE %(6)s END) AS "countRange", SUM(CASE WHEN "measurements_potatoes"."alternaria" > %(7)s THEN %(8)s ELSE %(9)s END) AS "countBigger" FROM "measurements_potatoes"
        Params: (1.0, 1, 0, 30.0, 50.0, 1, 0, 1.0, 1, 0)
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

any idea why the query is failing? or maybe is there an alternative to get the raw query to execute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Django ORM query will fail due to incorrect use of `.aggregate()` and `.order_by()` together.

`.aggregate()` is a **QuerySet** method, which is used to calculate aggregates over the entire QuerySet. Importantly, it does not return a QuerySet itself but instead returns a **Dictionary** *(See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/))*.

Since `.order_by()` is also a **QuerySet** method, not a **Dictionary** method, you therefore cannot chain it after `.aggregate()`.

Instead, you should use `.annotate()` if you want to group by **wn** and retain the QuerySet to order it.

The corrected approach therefore involves using `.annotate()` to compute the conditional sums per group, and then using `.order_by()` as needed on the result.

Here's how you can restructure your query accordingly:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When, IntegerField

res = (
    PotatoesMeasurement.objects
    .values('wn')
    .annotate(
        countSmaller=Sum(
            Case(
                When(alternaria__lte=1, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ),
        countRange=Sum(
            Case(
                When(alternaria__gte=20, alternaria__lt=30, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ),
        countBigger=Sum(
            Case(
                When(alternaria__gt=90, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )
    .order_by('wn')
)
```

Please note I've changed the `countRange` condition to use __gte and __lt for the range.

Now as for the **SQLDecodeError** being thrown, if the above does not fix the problem (which it hopefully will do), then it is possible there is a limitation in **Djongo**'s ability to translate these queries to **MongoDB**'s aggregation framework (Djongo being the Django ORM wrapper for MongoDB that you appear to be using).

I'm afraid I'm not a MongoDB expert so I can't help with that if the error does continue to be raised. But hopefully making the above change to your query means that you will be sending a pure QuerySet to Djongo, and that hopefully should be convertable into the MongoDB query and therefore your error should be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the usage of `order_by` and `aggregate` appreciate  also the docs. the query you restructured run OK however when try to check the value it throws the same error, I have found couple of topics here talking about the limitation of the Mongo aggregation framework support in Django so I'll try to switch over to another DB and test the same query. I'll post my update here

Comment: Thanks, @Ehsan - I'm not too surprised by that sadly; Django's ORM really wasn't built with NoSQL/MongoDB in mind (and likewise MongoDB was not built with Django in mind). The two are a real pain to get to work together, and although it is possible in most cases, if you have choice in the matter I always recommend against trying to combine the two technologies (and I have infinite respect for those who have no choice and so doggedly persevere!)

Comment: Just to confirm the limitation was due ORM support for MongoDB, I change the DB to SQLite3 and the above query worked perfectly.